# Get an expression as an input in python

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have an array of numbers that the user input. Now, I want the user to enter an expression (for example, sin (x)) and I want to evaluate the expression using the numbers from the array. 
I don't know how to get the expression as an input from the user and then to evaluate it based on the array.

So far I have:

```
collection = list()
number = input("Enter the number of elements you want: ")
for i in range(int(number)):
    n = input("Enter number:")
    collection.append(int(n))
print ('ARRAY: ',collection)

def function_creator(): 

    expr = input("Enter the function(in terms of x):") 
    x = int(input("Enter the value of x:")) 
    safe_dict['x'] = x 
    y = eval(expr, {"__builtins__":None}, safe_dict) 
    print("y = {}".format(y)) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    safe_list = ['acos', 'asin', 'atan', 'atan2', 'ceil', 'cos', 
                 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'exp', 'fabs', 'floor', 
                 'fmod', 'frexp', 'hypot', 'ldexp', 'log', 'log10', 
                 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 
                 'tan', 'tanh'] 
    safe_dict = dict([(k, locals().get(k, None)) for k in safe_list]) 

    function_creator()
```

I have tried getting the expression using the eval() function in python but couldn't get it to work. For the sake of working in steps, I'm not using the array right now as the x variable in the expression the user inputs. Instead, I'm just trying to evaluate the expression the user inputs with an x of their choice.  Any ideas on how to make it work or any other way in which I can get the function as an input?

Comment: What was `eval()` outputting that wasn't what you wanted?

Comment: `sin(x)` is not an equation; it's an expression. `sin(x) = y` would be an equation: an equation is something that *equates* two values.

Comment: please check edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work for expressions in x such as x*sin(x) + (x+1)*exp(2*x)

```
from math import *   # import sin, cos, tan, etc. into globals
                     # to allow use by eval

def function_creator(arr): 
  " allows expressions such as x*sin(x) + x "
  expr = input("Enter the function(in terms of x):")
  # x is bound locally inside the list comprehension for use by eval
  return [eval(expr) for x in arr]  # compute expression on each data element

if __name__ == "__main__": 
  collection = list()
  number = input("Enter the number of elements you want: ")
  for i in range(int(number)):
    n = input("Enter number:")
    collection.append(float(n))
  print ('ARRAY: ',collection)
  result = function_creator(collection)
  print(result)
```

Comment: This is just what I needed! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer**

You can import functions into the global scope, and then grab them from globals as follows:

```
from numpy import sin

collection = list()
number = input("Enter the number of elements you want: ")
for i in range(int(number)):
    n = input("Enter number:")
    collection.append(int(n))
print ('ARRAY: ',collection)

func_name = input("Enter function: ")

try:
    ans = globals()[func_name](collection)
except KeyError:
    raise AttributeError('Function not found in namespace!')

print(ans)
```

**Slightly more sophisticated answer**

You can try the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

collection = list()
number = input("Enter the number of elements you want: ")
for i in range(int(number)):
    n = input("Enter number:")
    collection.append(int(n))
print ('ARRAY: ',collection)

func_name = input("Enter function: ")

def getattr_loop(obj,attr):
    '''getattr, or getitem, or error, in a loop, forever!'''
    spl = attr.split('.')
    if len(spl) > 1:
        try:
            return getattr_loop(getattr(obj,spl[0]),'.'.join(spl[1:]))
        except AttributeError as err:
            try:
                return getattr_loop(obj[spl[0]],'.'.join(spl[1:]))
            except KeyError:
                raise err
    else:
        return getattr(obj,spl[0])

# Compute using user defined function
try:
    ans = getattr_loop(globals(),func_name)(collection)
except AttributeError:
    raise AttributeError('Function not found in namespace!')

print(ans)
```

`getattr_loop` is a function which will recursively search `obj` for attribute `attr`. The attribute given by `attr` automatically reads dot notation, and so you can use it to do some nifty tricks. It also has some handling to attempt `.__getitem__()` if there is no attribute (`obj[attr]`)

The downside is that `getattr_loop` will give you a `RecursionError` if you have a really deeply nested attribute in `obj`.

For example, if one uses the Numpy module as the object:

```
>>> getattr_loop(np,'random.rand')
```

This would allow you to access `np.random.rand`. If you use `globals()` as is used in the code snippet, it will grab all objects defined at the global scope. So, a user of the above code snippet can type 'np.sin' as the function, and the code will compute `np.sin(collection)`.

If you wish to use `sin` directly, you'll need to import that directly into the namespace.

**Caveat about security**

Grabbing things from `globals()` can be risky from a security perspective. If you need this to be secure, make sure to:

- sanitise your inputs
- construct an object which only contains the functions that you want someone to be able to access, lest you accidentally allow someone to patch into something like `os.remove` and do some harm...

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! However, i'm wondering if there's a way in which the input expression could be either a trigonometric function (sin, cos, tan) or a normal expression like (x+x or x*3x). From the code you gave me above, I could only make it work for trig expressions.